# Pair android device by bluetooth by entering PIN programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth

I used this library https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary to send and get messages from a microcontroller . but it needs to be paired with the device . i want to do it programmatically and enter pin from code . 
any suggestion ?

Edited :

public class TerminalActivity extends Activity 
{
    BluetoothSPP bt;

```
TextView textStatus, textRead;
EditText etMessage;

Menu menu;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_terminal);
    Log.i("Check", "onCreate");

    textRead = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textRead);
    textStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
    etMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMessage);

    bt = new BluetoothSPP(this);

    if(!bt.isBluetoothAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                , "Bluetooth is not available"
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    bt.setOnDataReceivedListener(new BluetoothSPP.OnDataReceivedListener() {
        public void onDataReceived(byte[] data, String message) {
            textRead.append(message + "\n");
        }
    });

    bt.setBluetoothConnectionListener(new BluetoothSPP.BluetoothConnectionListener() {
        public void onDeviceDisconnected() {
            textStatus.setText("Status : Not connect");
            menu.clear();
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_connection, menu);
        }

        public void onDeviceConnectionFailed() {
            textStatus.setText("Status : Connection failed");
        }

        public void onDeviceConnected(String name, String address) {
            textStatus.setText("Status : Connected to " + name);
            menu.clear();
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_disconnection, menu);
        }
    });
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_connection, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.menu_android_connect) {
        bt.setDeviceTarget(BluetoothState.DEVICE_ANDROID);
        /*
        if(bt.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED)
            bt.disconnect();*/
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceList.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
    } else if(id == R.id.menu_device_connect) {
        bt.setDeviceTarget(BluetoothState.DEVICE_OTHER);
        /*
        if(bt.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED)
            bt.disconnect();*/
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceList.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
    } else if(id == R.id.menu_disconnect) {
        if(bt.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED)
            bt.disconnect();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    bt.stopService();
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!bt.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, BluetoothState.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } else {
        if(!bt.isServiceAvailable()) {
            bt.setupService();
            bt.startService(BluetoothState.DEVICE_ANDROID);
            setup();
        }
    }
}

public void setup() {
    Button btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(etMessage.getText().length() != 0) {
                bt.send(etMessage.getText().toString(), true);
                etMessage.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            bt.connect(data);
    } else if(requestCode == BluetoothState.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            bt.setupService();
            bt.startService(BluetoothState.DEVICE_ANDROID);
            setup();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    , "Bluetooth was not enabled."
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

}

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling `createBond()` through reflection?

This works for me, with `device` being a `BluetoothDevice`:

```
    Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
    m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
```

EDIT: Also, if you want to set a particular pin, this should work:

```
byte[] pinBytes = convertPinToBytes("0000");
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("setPin", byte[].class);
m.invoke(device, pinBytes);
```